# Does google store all the IPs since you opened the account?

Tags: google, gmail

As in title: Does google store all the IPs since you opened the account? What to do to see all logs since I created a gmail account?

Answer (score 1):

From Google's [Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/):

> When you use Google services, we may collect and process information about your actual location. We use various technologies to determine location, including IP address, GPS, and other sensors that may, for example, provide Google with information on nearby devices, Wi-Fi access points and cell towers.

Unfortunately, this policy is vague regarding the retention time. As noted in [this paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1058&context=jpc), Google's policies regarding the anonymization often describe the "expected effects, rather than the process itself."

However, you can see some of the logged IP and location information:

At the bottom of the Gmail page, you can find a link next to the text "Currently being used in *x* other locations." This link will show some, but not all of your history.

If desired, it is possible enable more detailed location tracking on your [account history settings page](https://www.google.com/settings/accounthistory).